# How to delete a row from DOM on button click in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have an **HTML code** as shown below. I have copied this from DOM and it is generated through php.

```
<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;">
    <button type="button" onclick="removeRow()" name="delete_row[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="">Delete</button>
    <input type="text" name="code[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="AEFA">
    <input type="text" name="en_desc[]" value="Foreign Affairs and International Trade">
</div>

<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;">
    <button type="button" onclick="removeRow()" name="delete_row[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="">Delete</button>
    <input type="text" name="code[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="AGFO">
    <input type="text" name="en_desc[]" value="Agriculture and Forestry">
</div>
```

The above **HTML code** belongs to the following screenshot:

[image]

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what JS code I need to add so that on clicking Delete button it deletes a row containing that button.

For example: If I click the 2nd row **Delete** button, it should delete the **complete 2nd row** and if I click the 1st row **Delete** 
button, it should delete the **complete 1st row**.

This is what I have tried:

```
function removeRow() {
 document.queryselector(".house-senate-committee").remove();
}
```

Comment: Is changing the markup an option in your case?

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't change the DOM(HTML). Its generated through php.

Comment: Well, if it ever becomes an option, I would recommend keeping markup / styles / logic separate. Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/z93nu0c5/) based on the code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your buttons to have `onclick="removeRow(this)"`, you can then rewrite `removeRow` as below to remove that button's div when it is clicked.

```js
function removeRow(el) {
  el.parentNode.remove();
}
```

```html
<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;">
  <button type="button" onclick="removeRow(this)" name="delete_row[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="">Delete</button>
  <input type="text" name="code[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="AEFA">
  <input type="text" name="en_desc[]" value="Foreign Affairs and International Trade">
</div>

<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;">
  <button type="button" onclick="removeRow(this)" name="delete_row[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="">Delete</button>
  <input type="text" name="code[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="AGFO">
  <input type="text" name="en_desc[]" value="Agriculture and Forestry">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have copied the answer and it is working as I expected. The DOM which I have mentioned in the question above is generated through php. Here is the [php code](https://3v4l.org/757so) which I have used which is generating the DOM above.

Comment: On click of a **Delete** button, it deletes the row from the DOM but on refreshing the page, the **deleted row** comes back again because everything is pulled from the JSON. Here is the content in the JSON which I have **{"code":["AEFA","AGFO"], "en_desc":["Foreign Affairs and International Trade","Agriculture and Forestry"]}**

Comment: The question which I have is on click of a **Delete** button, it is deleting the row from the **DOM** through JS code but on refreshing the page the deleted row comes back again. I am wondering what **php code I need to add** so that on saving the form, it deletes the values from the JSON array for the deleted row.

Comment: Here is the updated [php code](https://3v4l.org/5JmGl) which is generating the DOM above.

Comment: I have posted the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60271281/how-to-delete-values-from-json-object-array-in-php) as well.

Comment: I received an answer from @Ebrahim Mohammed but I am wondering if you can give me clue how to approach that question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [closest](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jquery-closest-with-examples/) to achieve it like below

```js
function removeRow(element) {
  $(element).closest('.house-senate-committee').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;">
    <button type="button" onclick="removeRow(this)" name="delete_row[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="">Delete</button>
    <input type="text" name="code[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="AEFA">
    <input type="text" name="en_desc[]" value="Foreign Affairs and International Trade">
</div>

<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;">
    <button type="button" onclick="removeRow(this)" name="delete_row[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="">Delete</button>
    <input type="text" name="code[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="AGFO">
    <input type="text" name="en_desc[]" value="Agriculture and Forestry">
</div>
```